# How to detect browser in Elm

Tags: elm, browser-detection

How do I detect the browser from Elm?

Specifically I want to be able to tell if the web app is running on a tablet (Safari on iPad, etc.) or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Html.programWithFlags`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/latest/Html#programWithFlags) to pass information from Javascript to Elm on initialization.

Assuming you can infer browser from user agent, you could do something like this:

```elm
type alias Flags =
    { userAgent : String }
```

Your `init` would look like this:

```elm
init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
  ...

main =
    programWithFlags { init = init, ... }
```

And from Javascript, you would pass the flags in like this:

```js
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen({
    userAgent: navigator.userAgent
});
```

Side note: User agent may not be enough to fully detect browser. You can see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) which provides more reliable detection. Either way, the end result is that you would send some kind of flag along to the Elm app on init.

[More info on Flags can be found here.](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html#flags)

Comment: Any way to do this from Elm reactor?

Comment: No - Elm Reactor doesn't allow for custom ports or flags. However, if you want a lightweight dev server for Elm, check out [elm-live](https://github.com/tomekwi/elm-live). That has the same sort of feel as elm-reactor, but allows for custom pages wrapping and importing Elm files.

Comment: I don't think elm-live supports 0.18 yet

Comment: Elm-live supports 0.19 for a while now

Answer (score 1):

You can use `elm-vendor` package.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/coreytrampe/elm-vendor/latest

Comment: The undocumented Native (Kernel) code folks used for this kind of thing is no longer available as of 0.19 as it conflicts with DCE.